# How to compile java class (inside a package) without IDE

Tags: java

I'm working in windows 7, Java 7 and have following folder:

```
C:\..\myApplicationV
```

Inside this folder there are two folders with one java class each:

```
C:\..\myApplicationV\graphics\Circle.java
C:\..\myApplicationV\mains\UseCircle.java
```

Circle.java contains following code:

```
package graphics;

public class Circle {


    public void describeCircle (){

    System.out.println("A circle is round");

    }
}
```

I've been able to compile Circle.java so therefore I have also following file:

```
C:\..\myApplicationV\graphics\Circle.class
```

UseCircle.java contains following code:

```
package mains;

import graphics.Circle;

class UseCircle{

    public static void main (String[] args){

    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.describeCircle();

    }
}
```

I try to compile this last one class, I place in:

```
C:\..\myApplicationV\mains\
```

and type:

```
javac UseCircle.java
```

but I'm getting following message:

```
UseCircle.java:3: error: package graphics does not exist
import graphics.Circle;
               ^
```

Doing some research I have found some information at:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html
```

So I have solve this isuue by placing all java classes in one package and works fine. Also I have move UseCircle.java class to base folder:

```
C:\..\myApplicationV
```

And also works. The problem is when trying to use the two package. Do you know what could be wrong ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Answer (score 2):

Please specify the full package path while compiling

```
cd C:\..\myApplicationV\
javac mains/UseCircle.java
java mains/UseCircle
```

Comment: The package is `mains`

Comment: Also note, to execute you need to use the period to separate packages. So, the command would be `java mains.UseCircle`. Slash wouldn't work.

Comment: Odd. It didn't work for me. Even stranger, the other slash (`/`) worked. Any setting that I missed?

Comment: Oops!! @Vincnet  I got typos!!! It should be slash instead of back slash. I'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open the command prompt in myApplicationV folder & do the following:

```
javac graphics\Circle.java
javac mains\UseCircle.java
java mains.UseCircle
```